# Get value inside array?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I already got the component value like this:

```
components = "Set(['LPE', 'CLK'])"
```

I don't want to be like this:

```
print components 
Set(['LPE', 'CLK'])
```

How can I print/get value like this only?

```
LPE
CLK
```

Comment: is Set is your own module or in-build `set` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solve by doing split:

```
components = "Set(['LPE', 'CLK'])"
x = components.lstrip("Set([").rstrip("])")
for i in x.split(", "):
    z = i.lstrip("'").rstrip("'")
    print z
```

Answer (score 1):

**If Set is set:**

```
>>> c = "set(['LPE', 'CLK'])"
>>> eval(c)
set(['LPE', 'CLK'])
>>> for i in eval(c):
...     print i
...
LPE
CLK
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> neglect
['(', ')', "'", ',', '[', ']', 'e', 't', 'S']
>>> result=""
>>> for words in components:
...     if(words in neglect):
...             if(words == ','):
...                     result = result +  " "
...     else:
...             result = result + words
... 
>>> result
'LPE  CLK'
```

Answer (score 1):

Its easy to use `eval` function to do this, 
The `eval` function lets a python program run python `code` within itself.

```
var="set(['LPE', 'CLK'])"
print eval(a)
```

Output:

```
set(['LPE', 'CLK'])
```

Then use for loop,

```
for i in set(['LPE', 'CLK']):
     print i
```

Output:

```
LPE
CLK
```

### OR

```
>>> for i in eval("set(['LPE', 'CLK'])"):
...    print i
...
LPE
CLK
```

Answer (score 0):

convert from set to list. component_list = list(set(['LPE','CLK']))
 and  print component_list[0], component_list[1]